# sqlpackage publish action stuck on Initializing deployment status

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlpackage

I have the below `powershell` script:

```
$sqlpackagepublish = Start-Process -FilePath sqlpackage.exe -ArgumentList '/Action:Publish','/SourceFile:"Database Services\bin\Release\Database Services.dacpac"',"/TargetConnectionString:""Data Source=${Env};Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Initial catalog=${Target}""","/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=${Data_loss}" -wait -PassThru -Credential $Cred -RedirectStandardOutput sqlstdout.txt -RedirectStandardError sqlstderr.txt
$sqlpackagepublish.WaitForExit()
$sqlpackagepublish

if ($sqlpackagepublish.ExitCode -eq 0) {
     Get-Content sqlstdout.txt
 }
else {
     echo "An error occurred"
     Get-Content sqlstderr.txt
     exit $sqlpackagepublish.ExitCode
}
```

When I ran the code against `sqlserver` dev server, it works.
Once I tried to deploy it against `sqlserver` prod server it stuck (the `jenkins` job is already running 30 minutes) with:

```
Initializing deployment (Start)
```

is there a way to debug it to understand what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with running `sp_who2` on the database server to see if `sqlpackage` has made a connection to it, and if it's blocking on the server somewhere.

If so, you can further investigate with the SQL Server Profiler (can be found in the Tools menu of SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: Tnx, I've found the issue. I will post new thread for it :)

Comment: @arielma - what was the issue? seeing the same issue using https://github.com/markhobson/docker-sqlpackage